# Images not matching with titles

Tags: php, wordpress

Could some body help with this?

I have this code which prints 4 picture articles on a row.

```
    <article>

<div class="post-thumbnail img">

<?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image'); endif; ?>

</div>
<!--/.post-thumbnail-->

</article>
```

[image]

Any time i try to add a subtitle, it does not stay on a row any more. like this

```
<article>

<div class="post-thumbnail img">

<?php if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image'); endif; ?>

</div>
<div class="post-thumbnail img">
<?php the_title();?>

</div>
<!--/.post-thumbnail-->

</article>
```

What happens is, the fist image text will be below the image, the rest will be on top..But all needs to be below those images.
[image]
Any solution?

CSS`

```
.post-thumbnail img { 
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: -16px;

    float: left;
    width: 23.0%; 
     margin-right: 2%}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You should give us the HTML code generated by the PHP function.

So far, I don't know if you haven't made a mistake in your CSS code :

```
/* .post-thumbnail img = get the <img> inside a <div class="post-thumbnail"> */
/* .post-thumbnail.img = get the <div class="post-thumbnail img"> */
.post-thumbnail.img { 
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: -16px;
    float: left;
    width: 23.0%; 
    margin-right: 2%;
}
```

Hope that help.